# Is there a way the make \label behave like a hyperlink

Tags: labels, hyperlink

Suppose I have something like this in my document:

```
\begin{example}  \label{exam:Blah}
blah blah
\end{example}
```

Later in the document I write:  ... the interested reader should look at Example \vref{exam:Blah}. and I get something like:

... The interested reader should look at Example X.Y on page Z.

I would like the reader to be able to click on the text Example X.Y on page Z and jump to that location.

I've loaded package hyperref and that works for inserting links, but I can't figure out a way to marry that with labeling.

Comment: `\vref` is from the varioref package? Normally what it produces would be hyperlinked if hyperref is loaded as well. If it's not working for you can you post a complete [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that shows the problem, so we don't have to guess what packages and options you're using, and how, e.g., the `example` environment is defined?

Comment: @frabjous. I didn't know that varioref and hyperref were supposed to work together like that. Perhaps they do and I just never thought to click on a cross reference. I will test it out. If it doesn't work I'll post the code.

Comment: @frabjous. I'll be damned. It worked! Exactly the way I wanted it to work. No extra steps involved, just \label{} and \vref{}, which means I don't have to go back through my document and change things. Perfect! Just my opinion but I think that little piece of intel deserves to be an answer.

Comment: I didn't think it would be that easy to answer your question either, but sure, I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `\vref` and similar commands from the varioref package are used, and the hyperref package is also loaded, the crossreference will automatically be made  into a hyperlink to the corresponding `\label`-ed item.

(As Mico mentions in the comments, if you load both packages explicitly in your document, hyperref should be loaded after varioref. In most cases, hyperref should be loaded last or close to last.)

Incidentally, if for some reason you *didn't* want them to be hyperlinks, you could use the starred versions, e.g., `\vref*{exam:Blah}` instead.

Comment: +1, You may want to mention explicitly that if a document loads both packages, `hyperref` must be loaded *after* `varioref`.

Comment: Thank you. I hope this will be helpful to other novices.

Comment: Don't be dismayed if your TOC disappears after you load hyperref and compile  -- it comes back after the second compile.